# I want to create a corpus in python from multiple text files

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I want to do text analytics on some text data. Issue is that so far i have worked on CSV file or just 1 file, but here I have multiple text files. So, my approach is to combine them all to 1 file and then use nltk to do some text pre processing and further steps.

I tried to download gutenberg pkg from nltk, and I am not getting any error in the code. But I am not able to see content of 1st text file in 1 cell, 2nd text file in 2nd cell and so on. Kindly help.

```
filenames = [
    "246.txt",
    "276.txt",
    "286.txt",
    "344.txt",
    "372.txt",
    "383.txt",
    "388.txt",
    "392.txt",
    "556.txt",
    "665.txt"
]
with open("result.csv", "w") as f:
    for filename in filenames:
        f.write(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw(filename))
```

Expected result - I should get 1 csv file with contents of these 10 texts files listed in 10 different rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = [
    "246.txt",
    "276.txt",
    "286.txt",
    "344.txt",
    "372.txt",
    "383.txt",
    "388.txt",
    "392.txt",
    "556.txt",
    "665.txt"
]
with open("result.csv", "w") as f:
    for index, filename in enumerate(filenames):
        f.write(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw(filename))
        # Append a comma to the file content when
        # filename is not the content of the
        # last file in the list.
        if index != (len(filenames) - 1):
            f.write(",")
```

Output:

`this,is,a,sentence,spread,over,multiple,files,and,the end`

Code and .txt files available at https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/stackoverflow.com-questions-57081411 .

Using Python 2.7.15+ and nltk 3.4.4 . I had to move the .txt files to /home/mh/nltk_data/corpora/gutenberg .

Comment: Thanks Michael. I guess with this approach, we need to place all text files in Gutenberg folder.I got to do the same using glob library in python.

Comment: Most welcome. Please upvote if the answer is useful.